# I am having problems reassigning a variable in python

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

I am trying to create a text adventure game in python. I am using randint to create a number between 0 and 2 and when I use an if statement to take the random number and assign the biome variable to a biome type it instead takes the original version of the variable and uses that as the biome.

```
#Defines game()
print ('''You are in a %s biome.'''%(biome))
biome='placeholder'
import random
trees=random.randint(0,50)
biomes=random.randint(0,2)
animals=random.randint(0,3)
wolves=random.randint(0,5)
if biomes == "0":
    biome='Forest'

if biomes == "1":
    biome='Taiga'

if biomes == "2":
    biome='Mountain'

print ('''You are in a %s biome.'''%(biome))
```

Comment: The answers to your question are correct, but Python makes this even easier with [`random.choice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice): `biome = random.choice(['Forest', 'Taiga', 'Mountain'])`

Answer (score 4):

`biomes` is int value. `"0"` is string value.

Both values never can be equal.

```
>>> 0 == "0"
False
```

Use int literal.

```
if biomes == 0:
    biome = 'Forest'
elif biomes == 1:
    biome = 'Taiga'
elif biomes == 2: # else
    biome = 'Mountain'
```

I recommed you to use [random.choice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random#random.choice) as other suggested. Simple, eaiser to read.

```
>>> random.choice(['Forest', 'Taiga', 'Mountain'])
'Mountain'
>>> random.choice(['Forest', 'Taiga', 'Mountain'])
'Mountain'
>>> random.choice(['Forest', 'Taiga', 'Mountain'])
'Taiga'
```

Comment: You don't need three seperate `if` conditions here. :)

Comment: it's even better as a dict. . . biome_map = {0: 'forest', 1: 'taiga', : 'mountain'} then it's just biome = biome_map.get(biomes)

Comment: @GoingTharn, `random.choice(..)` is more pythoic as other suggest.

Comment: @GoingTharn, And list/tuple is enough. (`['Forest', 'Tiaga', 'Mountain']`) Because index is continuous (0, 1, 2 only).

Answer (score 2):

`random.randint(...)` returns an integer. You are comparing the value to a string here.

```
>>> type(randint(0, 2))
<type 'int'>
```

Your `if` statements should be rewritten as -

```
if biomes == 0:
    biome='Forest'
elif biomes == 1:
    biome='Taiga'
else:
    biome='Mountain'
```

**P.S**-- You don't need three `if` statements, since, if the value is `0`, it can never be `1` or `2`, so no need to check the conditions. You can use an `if-elif-else` construct instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more understandable way:

```
from random import choice
biomes = ['Forest', 'Tiaga', 'Mountain']
biome = choice(biomes)
```

Then if the number of biomes increases, or decreases, you don't have to worry about updating the range for the random number, and not quite getting your `if` statements right...

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare to `0` rather than the string value`"0"`  as in `if biome == 0:`

However, this can be simplified with `random.choice` to select a biome randomly from a list.

```
biome = random.choice(['Forest', 'Taiga', 'Mountain'])
```

and eliminate your `if`s altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try in the if statement biome == 1 instead of biome == "1" and the same for  biome == 2 and biome == 3.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are comparing an integer value to a string (which will never equal).  This will work:

```
import random
trees=random.randint(0,50)
biomes=random.randint(0,2)
animals=random.randint(0,3)
wolves=random.randint(0,5)

# Compare biomes (which is an integer) to another integer
if biomes == 0:
    biome='Forest'

# Use elif for multiple comparisons like that
elif biomes == 1:
    biome='Taiga'

# Use an else here because the only other option is 2
else:
    biome='Mountain'

print ('''You are in a %s biome.'''%(biome))
```

Note also I removed the first and second lines of your script.  The first would have blown up because `biome` isn't defined yet and the second does nothing.